# Votes appearing after an interval of Time

Tags: discussion, feature-request, timeline

I have noticed (and maybe I am wrong) that existing votes of an answer (or question) influence the total votes received.

It is more a philosophical problem of the relation [between part and whole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-whole_theory)

That is probably due to the fact that upvotes or downvotes appear instantaneously.

So when a user clicks a new question existing upvotes or downvotes influence him, until the user shapes his own point of view, and it is probable for him to vote accordingly to previous votes.

I have to mention that there is (in my point of view) a crucial time for the rhythm (of upvoting or downvoting a question or an answer) to be stabilized.

What do you think about total votes appearing after an interval of time, for example, after 5 minutes since the time that have been posted?

Answer (score 1):

It adds quite a bit of complexity, as for that interval, each voter would see *their* votes take effect, but nobody else's.

In my opinion, this was already solved by adding the random sort order to posts that have the same number of votes.

Comment: I wouldn't say the problem is "solved" - it still effectively makes the first vote cast for answers on any question more likely to be influential than any subsequent vote - but I agree that the additional complexity wouldn't be worth any potential benefit.